# How to use Jenkins Pipeline and choose triggers for email notifications?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Before Pipeline, I used [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to define triggers for sending emails (on first failure, and when back to success).

But in the Pipeline version, I can't control the triggers, I can only "send always", or send based on current build result.

How do I send emails in pipeline based on more general triggers? (first failure, first success, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While setting up jenkins pipeline, you have a `Pipeline Syntax` link below the Groovy Script Editor like in the picture below.

[image]

Clicking on the link takes you to snippet generator like in the picture below.
[image]

Here I've selected emailext : Extended plugin option. You can select simple mail option from the dropdown as well and generate the snippet.

To determine the build status of the current job Jenkins provides the environmental variables which you can use while writing your groovy script. You can find the list of global environment variables by clicking the link provided at the end of Snippet Generator page.[image]

Below is the list of properties of `currentBuild` environment variable for your reference.

```
    The currentBuild variable may be used to refer to the currently running build.
    It has the following readable properties:

    numberbuild number (integer)
    resulttypically SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE (may be null for an ongoing build)
    currentResulttypically SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE. Will never be null.
    resultIsBetterOrEqualTo(String)Compares the current build result to the provided result string (SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE) and returns true if the current build result is better than or equal to the provided result.
    resultIsWorseOrEqualTo(String)Compares the current build result to the provided result string (SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE) and returns true if the current build result is worse than or equal to the provided result.
    displayNamenormally #123 but sometimes set to, e.g., an SCM commit identifier
    descriptionadditional information about the build
    idnormally number as a string
    timeInMillistime since the epoch when the build was scheduled
    startTimeInMillistime since the epoch when the build started running
    durationduration of the build in milliseconds
    durationStringa human-readable representation of the build duration
    previousBuildanother similar object, or null
    nextBuildsimilarly
    absoluteUrlURL of build index page
    buildVariablesfor a non-Pipeline downstream build, offers access to a map of defined build variables; for a Pipeline downstream build, any variables set globally on env
    changeSetsa list of changesets coming from distinct SCM checkouts; each has a kind and is a list of commits; each commit has a commitId, timestamp, msg, author, and affectedFiles each of which has an editType and path; the value will not generally be Serializable so you may only access it inside a method marked @NonCPS
    rawBuilda hudson.model.Run with further APIs, only for trusted libraries or administrator-approved scripts outside the sandbox; the value will not be Serializable so you may only access it inside a method marked @NonCPS


    Additionally, for this build only (but not for other builds), the following properties are writable:
resultdisplayNamedescription
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I know all of this, but it doesn't answer my question. It's missing the part of the more general triggers - like first failure, first success, etc (like in the original plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in pipeline [post build steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions). You can look at this [documentation](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/sending-notifications-pipeline) if you are using scripted pipeline and [this doc](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/) for declarative pipeline examples

Comment: It's missing the part of the more general triggers - like first failure, first success, etc. (like in the original plugin). Any idea on how to use them?

Comment: May be changed condition will help you

Comment: Changed condition? What is it? What do you mean?

Comment: Check the post build steps in link posted. There is a post build condition like that